# How to access component variable inside style in single file in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

Is there any vue plugin that can allows us to use template variable in side `<style/>` tag in *Single File Components* for e.g.

```
<template>

    <div>{{ display }}</div>

</template>


<script>

    export default {
        data(){
            return { display: 'block' }
        }
    }

</script>


<style>
    body {
        display: {{ display }}
    }
</style>
```

Any better way/plugin to do this??

*I already have known about `:style` and `:class`*

Comment: You would do this using CSS classes designed for this purpose, not by directly manipulating CSS rules.

Comment: Yes I got you! but when we want @media css manipulation then its become issue!

Comment: I don't see how that use case would require any different approach.

Comment: @connexo think like you want different image on desktop and different image on mobile!

Comment: You'd do that with CSS... No Javascript involved at all.

Comment: but my images urls are coming from API only, and I don't have any access to the backend, completely REST API only

Comment: Running into the same issue @YogeshJagdale , how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no way to access the Vue model (data layer) inside `<Style>` in the current version of Vue.  Vue only control the DOM tree but not help you work around on CSSOM.

You are probably using WebPack or other bundler and writing modularized component in single file where you have `<template>`, `<script>`, and `<style>`.  Your bundler will have a way to convert `<template>` into Vue render function, but `style` here is purely css and will be bundled into a single css file.

If you want to set a styling value dynamically that controlled by your component, you need to find a way to inject them in run-time, i.e. using the Vue version of `styled-component` (as they came from React originally).  But you will lose the caching ability, unless you also save the value in localStorage.

Answer (score -1):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

You can put whatever you want in your style attribute by binding inline styles:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>
```

Comment: "I already have known about :style and :class" said on the Question, please don't put a generic answer